# SBT on Mac M2 architecture not compiling modules in parallel in fork mode

Tags: java, scala, sbt, apple-m1

It dramatically slows my build time down.

Every module is compiled in sequence rather than in parallel when SBT is in "fork" mode.

On my old mac, non-M architecture, it compiled as many unrelated modules concurrently as possible. No SBT settings have changed.

I've tried a variety of java distros.

Current setup is:

- SBT 1.8.2 installed with SDKMan
- Eclipse Adoptium Java 17.0.4.1 installed with SDKMan

Anyone got any hints on how to get parallelisation back? What settings I'm missing?

Comment: can you check that you're running jdk compiled for arm64? One way you can do it via `sbt console` and when console is launched, execute `System.getProperty("os.arch")` and it should print `aarch64`

Comment: It does print `aarch64` yep.

Comment: I've narrowed down the issue and if I run SBT forked, then it can't compile in parallel (presumably can't test in parallel too but I've yet to check).

If I run SBT in non-forked mode then it can compile in parallel